# Show captions in HLS.JS player

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I am trying to turn on captions (*.ts format) in HLS.JS, but I can't found out how.
Here is hls.js player's official demo website:
https://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/
There is video with CC (Closed Captions) named: "CNN special report, with CC".
It is playing, but not showing CC. There is some sort of controls beneath, but nothing about subtitles/cc.
I checked in Dev mode: hls.subtitleTracks = []

However, if I load this video into VLC player or *.ts chunks, then I can turn on subtitles within VLC player.

Please, tell me how to turn on Closed Captions on that website or through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Omg, I found it. I should have just hover on player's UI and find three small dots in right bottom corner. There is control for Captions. 
Hope somebody will save time on this.